# Why wont my car key turn over?

Tags: starting, hyundai, santa-fe

we got a new battery and starter put on the car but after a couple times driving it, it stops turning over what could this be ?

Its a santa fe 2004

Comment: Tough situation.  How many miles on the odometer?  Did you do the work yourself, or bring it to a garage?  Sounds like loose or damaged wire somewhere, or more likely a dead alternator.   Does the starter motor spin and spin and the car not start, or does the starter motor not spin at all?  Are you doing this work yourself (as a beginner hobby mechanic?)

Comment: It could be the plastic ignition switch not making contact in crank position. Hyundai's and Kia's also had a problem with the spindles on the back of the ignition lock assembly twisting/bending so your not able to make the complete turn into crank position.